# Is there option group on Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'd like to have a `option group` (like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)) on a vuetify `select`.

Is that possible? And if it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**OUTDATED** : See @DevNik answer below for proper implementation

---

You can do this adding `divider` in your select's data and using `template` to have a better control over how your select is displaying data.

Like this :

**HTML**

```
<v-select
    v-model="peopleSelected"
    :items="people"
    box
    chips
    color="blue-grey lighten-2"
    label="Select"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="name"
    multiple
  >
    <!-- Template for render selected data -->
    <template
      slot="selection"
      slot-scope="data"
    >
      <v-chip
        :selected="data.selected"
        close
        class="chip--select-multi"
        @input="remove(data.item)"
      >
        {{ data.item.name }}
      </v-chip>
    </template>
    <!-- Template for render data when the select is expanded -->
    <template
      slot="item"
      slot-scope="data"
    >
      <!-- Divider and Header-->
      <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
        <v-list-tile-content v-text="data.item"/>
      </template>
      <!-- Normal item -->
      <template v-else>
        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title v-html="data.item.name"/>
          <v-list-tile-sub-title v-html="data.item.group"/>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

**Data**

```
data: () => ({
    peopleSelected:[],
    people: [
        { header: 'Group 1' },
        { name: 'Sandra Adams', group: 'Group 1' },
        { name: 'Ali Connors', group: 'Group 1' },
        { name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1' },
        { name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1'},
        { divider: true },
        { header: 'Group 2' },
        { name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2'},
        { name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2'},
        { name: 'John Smith', group: 'Group 2' },
        { name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2' }
      ]
  })
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxLXBN)

Comment: Demo seems to be broken

Comment: also answer this overcomplicates matters as they did not ask for `multiple` or `chips` behavior

Answer (score 16):

Seems that vuetify now offers this functionality itself. See the example model of the vuetify doku: [image: vuetify doc]

So you have to give the array ’items' only an object at the desired position.

Example `{'header': 'Mitarbeiter'}`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Vuetify 3 doesn't have the options suggested above, so Doing some research, I found a temporary solution using the item slot that changes the markup of each item inside of the list. Note that the `v-bind="props"` is what makes the element clickable/selectable

```html
<v-select
    label="Select food"
    :items="[
        { props: { header: 'Fruits' } },
        {
            title: 'Pineapple',
        },
        {
            title: 'Apple',
        },
        { props: { divider: true } },
        { props: { header: 'Vegetables' } },
        {
            title: 'Lettuce',
        },
        {
            title: 'Broccoli',
        },
    ]"
>
    <template #item="{ props, item }">
        <v-list-subheader v-if="props.header">
            {{ props.header }}
        </v-list-subheader>
        <v-divider v-else-if="props.divider" class="mt-2" />
        <v-list-item v-else v-bind="props"></v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for Vuetify v2, but hopefully it will also work with v3

Here is how I implemented it

Simple v-select tag with regular options

```html
    <v-select
        :items="groupedBreeds"
        v-model="breed"
        placeholder="e.g XXXX"
        outlined
        dense
    ></v-select>
```

The main difference is how I defined my data for :items attribute. Below is the my sample code

```js
export const groupedBreeds = [
    { header: 'Cattle breeds' },
    'Banteng',
    'Sumba Ongole',
    'Ongole Grade',
    'Madura',
    'Pasundan',
    'Pesisir cattle',
    'Aceh cattle',
    { divider: true },
    { header: 'Buffalo breeds' },
    'Kalang',
    'Pampangan buffalo',
    'Simelue buffalo',
    'Moa buffalo',
    'Sumbawa buffalo',
    { divider: true },
    { header: 'Other' },
    'Other',
]
```

Key value pair will also work for items in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

`Amandeep Singh` was right but here is another version using `item-text` and `item-value` props

```html
<template>
    <v-select
        label="label"
        :items="options"
        item-text="name"
        item-value="value"
    >
    </v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            options: [
                {
                    header: 'Group 1',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Item 1.1',
                    value: '1.1',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Item 1.2',
                    value: '1.2',
                },
                {
                    divider: true,
                },
                {
                    header: 'Group 2',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Item 2.1',
                    value: '2.1',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Item 2.2',
                    value: '2.2',
                },
            ],
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```